# Get text from xml - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I have this xml online http://64.182.231.116/~spencerf/test.xml

And I am trying to get the two text values `Assorted Cereal` and `Yogurt Parfait (2)`. Here is how I am currently parsing it, and I get the values I want as well as all the values under then, all the numbers and such, but I just want to get the names, and I am struggling how to just do that, any help or guidance would be great. Here is my code:

```
String currentDay = "";
        String currentMeal = "";
        String counter = "";
        String icon1 = "";

        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> itemsByCounter = new LinkedHashMap<String , List<String>>();
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();



        while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xmlData.getName();

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                        currentDay = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                        currentMeal = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter") && currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                        counter = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("name") && counter != null && currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                        icon1 = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "icon1");
                        Log.i(TAG, "icon1: " + icon1);
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                    if (currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal) && counter !=(null)) {
                        if (xmlData.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                            //Here gets everything but I just want 2 names
                            Log.i(TAG, "data: " + xmlData.getText());
                            items.add(xmlData.getText().trim().replaceAll(" +", " "));

                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter")) {
                        if (items.size() > 0) {
                            itemsByCounter.put(counter, items);
                            items = new ArrayList<String>();
                            recordsFound++;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = xmlData.next();
```

So as you can see in the comment in my code I am getting everything under the name tag, back but I just want the value of the name, and not all the other stuff.

Comment: Include a sample of your xml in the question itself. Then it's always available to people looking at your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the name in its own child element (meaning put an end tag before the nutritional facts). Under each `dish`, you could have this:

```
<name>Assorted Cereal</name>
<nutrition_facts> ... </nutrition_facts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but could do it along these lines:

```
List<Nutrition_Facts> nutrition_facts = new ArrayList<Nutrition_Facts>();
XMLDOMParser parser = new XMLDOMParser();
AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
InputStream stream;
try {       
    stream = manager.open("test.xml"); //need full path to your file here - mine is stored in assets folder
    Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);
}catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.printf("Error reading map %s\n", ex.getMessage());
}
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("nutrition_facts");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
    String name; 
    if (elementName.equals(e.getAttribute("Assorted Cereal"))){
        name = e.getAttribute("name");
        //do some stuff

    }
 }

//XMLDOMParser Class
public class XMLDOMParser {
    //Returns the entire XML document 
    public Document getDocument(InputStream inputStream) {
        Document document = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
            document = db.parse(inputSource);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return document;
    }

    /*
     * I take a XML element and the tag name, look for the tag and get
     * the text content i.e for <employee><name>Kumar</name></employee>
     * XML snippet if the Element points to employee node and tagName 
     * is name I will return Kumar. Calls the private method 
     * getTextNodeValue(node) which returns the text value, say in our 
     * example Kumar. */
    public String getValue(Element item, String name) {
        NodeList nodes = item.getElementsByTagName(name);
        return this.getTextNodeValue(nodes.item(0));
    }

    private final String getTextNodeValue(Node node) {
        Node child;
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                child = node.getFirstChild();
                while(child != null) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                    child = child.getNextSibling();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```